# Set Specific Font in android actionBar

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbar, action, typeface

i'm trying to set sans serif thin font in my android app. 
I was able to set that in a listview, now i want to do the same in action bar and in settings spinner, but i'm having troubles, anybody can help me ?

thanks

EDIT: i've found solution here -> http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/

EDIT:CLOSED

Comment: i'm working with styles.xml in values-14 folder ... am i doing right ?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){

final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg_warning));
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("**"
+ Stringa + "**"));

}

It set the withe title. 
Try to add the tag on XML
 style:"font-family="nome_font"